# Defining Functions Inside Functions

Tags: java, function, scope

I'm trying to define functions inside of another function but I get errors.

```java
void foo (int first) {
  int doubled = first * 2;
  int addNums (int second) {
    return doubled + second;
  }
  addNums(3);
}
```

Is this the wrong way to define a function? What am I doing wrong? I need the function to be defined within another because it requires variables that are scoped to the outer function.

Comment: Who said you could define a function inside a function?

Comment: onCreate {
addTwo(2);
} THEN 
int addTwo(int num) {
  return num + 2;
}

Comment: So you're telling me I need to define it outside of the `onCreate()` block?

Comment: That fixed it, thanks CmosBattery!

Comment: For the record: please read [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't write a method inside another method in Java. If it needs variables from the `onCreate()` method, then you must pass their values into your method as parameters.

Comment: ...or stored them in class member variables

Comment: @John3136 That's true, although I wouldn't promote them to member variables if it's just to get access to them in the method. I would only do that if it makes sense for the class to have that state, which, in what is likely an `Activity` or a `Fragment`, it probably does not make sense to make it stateful.

Answer (score -1):

Just create the function in the class and then use it from within onCreate.